# can an ldr memory load instruction ..load from the stack part of the memory

Tags: assembly, arm, stack-memory

I have this set of arm instructions in mind.

```
sub r3,sp,4    
ldr r1, [r3]
```

just for clarity can a normal ldr instruction load a value from the stack part of the memory?.

Comment: Have you tried?  Why do you think it might not?  The stack is not special, it's just memory.

Comment: There is no "stack part of memory", there is just memory that is close to (typically at higher addresses) an address that is (currently) pointed to by a stack pointer in some context.

Comment: @fuz just wanted a professional opinion .. because I know a colleague who was working on a binary analysis project and had different models of the memory and the stack. his work didn't involve updating the memory model but only the stack model every time he came across a push instruction. so now I know what could be going wrong in his tool.

Comment: @hanyerfan On ARM, stack memory is just normal memory.  There isn't anything special about this.  Some strange architectures (like 8086 with segmentation) may have execution models with special stack memory, but this is not the case on ARM.

Comment: @EOF: To be slightly fair, under an OS with memory protection (like Linux), "the stack" is its own mapping in virtual address space (in `/proc/<PID>/maps`.  It even has some special properties, like growing the mapping up to the `ulimit -s` on page faults when the stack pointer is below the bottom of the current mapping.  A more precise way to make your point is that stack memory is part of the same address-space as everything else, and it's not at all rare to take the address of stack variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.  The stack is just a particular region of the 32-bit virtual address space, and pointers into that region can live in any register, not just `sp`.

It is extremely common to access the stack through loads and stores using something other than `sp` as the base register.  Higher-level languages often do this, e.g.:

```
void func(void) {
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    // ...
}
```

The address of `x`, which is on the stack, would be put into `r1` to pass to `scanf`.  And `scanf` will do something like `str r2, [r1]` to store the input number there.  `scanf` neither knows nor cares whether `r1` points into stack or heap or whatever other part of the address space.

Any sort of emulation or modeling tool needs to account for this kind of aliasing.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can. This is actually how the `PUSH` and `POP` commands work. Most of the time you can use unified syntax to not have to write them, but they actually look like this. (Full disclosure: the only ARM CPU I have experience with is ARM7TDMI so I don't know for a fact this hasn't changed.)

```
STMFD sp!,{r0-r12}  ;ARM32 equivalent of PUSH  R0-R12
LDMFD sp!,{r0-r12}  ;ARM32 equivalent of POP R0-R12
```